# Изучение OpenGL под C++

Tags: glut, 3d, c++, opengl

Решил потихоньку поучить OpenGL под C++. Сначала начал (2 дня) с GLUT, он рекомендовался для начала, но сейчас прочитал, что он уже фактически deprecated и по-серьёзному не используется.
Подскажите, подойдёт ли мне для начала обучения SDL? Судя по мною прочитанному, он самый современный.
Мне будет даже лучше, если всё будет не быстро вставать (как в GLUT, что есть его преимущество), а если больше надо самому делать, чтобы разобраться в глубине технологии, как что происходит.

Answer (score 3):

Всем известно, что OpenGL - это библиотека функций, т.е. там нет никаких классов и шаблонов. Фактически можно юзать Си. Если хотите ощутить всю мощь ООП и OpenGL'а в одной связке используйте Qt (достаточно Qt Creator). Процесс создания графического окна там тоже относительно прост. Похож на C++ Builder.

Answer (score 1):

> Решил потихоньку поучить OpenGL под C++. Сначала начал (2 дня) с GLUT, он рекомендовался для начала, но сейчас прочитал, что он уже фактически deprecated и по-серьёзному не используется.

По серьёзному он вроде никогда не использовался. Вообще glut вроде коммерческий и заброшенный, и вместо него используют открытый freeglut, который вроде бы ещё обновляется. И вообще, ты же его собрался только поначалу использовать? Тогда вообще не важно что.

> Мне будет даже лучше, если всё будет не быстро вставать (как в GLUT, что есть его преимущество), а если больше надо самому делать, чтобы разобраться в глубине технологии, как что происходит.

Лучше возьми какой-нибудь пример оконного приложения и разберись в нём. Например такие примеры есть ближе к концу книги OpenGL SuperBible для разных ОС.

Comment: Пока что я делал только примеры прямоугольниками и полигонами.  
Ещё я нашёл классную книгу RedBook. Начал читать.

Comment: Самая классная книга по OpenGL - спецификация. В ней подробно описаны все функции вплоть до OpenGL 4.3, который вышел совсем недавно. Правда для новичков спецификация не очень годится.

Comment: @GLmonster, да, но ведь она не объясняет сами принципы работы для таких как я, кто не знает ещё этого.

Comment: @GLmonster, эх, вот вечно так:  
в RedBook используются `glBegin()/glEnd()`, которые, оказывается, уже `deprecated`. Говорят, нужно юзать VBO какое-то. То есть редбук теперь не читать?

Comment: Какой год выпуска, язык? Наверное это какое-то древнее издание. А по новому OpenGL книг на русском нет.

Comment: @GLmonster, я онлайн вот тут читал: http://fly.cc.fer.hr/~unreal/theredbook/  
Да мне, собственно, без разницы, на русском или на английском. Главное, чтоб новое.

Comment: Ну да, это старая книга. Вроде написано про OpenGL 3.0, а по содержанию и на OpenGL 2.0 не тянет. Поищи OpenGL Superbible 5 издание. Там устаревшие возможности не используются, но в начале книги есть их эмуляция в их библиотеке, потому что с ними легче начать изучать OpenGL, чем начиная всё с нуля.

 Вот ещё несколько уроков по OpenGL 3.3 http://code.google.com/p/gl33lessons/